# Validate number of decimal places in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Using FastAPI (and pydantic), is there a built-in way to validate the number of decimal places of a query parameter?

For example, I want to allow monetary values in USD only, such that only 2 decimal places are allowed. For example, 12.34 would be allowed, but 12.345 would not as it has 3 decimal places.

Here is my current code:

```py
@app.post("send_usd")
async def send_usd(amount: Decimal = Query(gt=0)):
    pass
```

Is there a built-in way (without writing a custom validator or regex) similar to the following example:

```py
amount: Decimal = Query(gt=0, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Do you want to validate that the input has only 2 decimal places or do you want pydantic to coerce the values so that they're always 2 decimal places? Pydantic is primarily a parsing library, with a basic support for adding validation, so if you want to validate the value, you may need to write a custom validator.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I generally advocate integer pennies.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `amount` need to be passed via querystring? If you can use the body instead, this could be an option:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from decimal import Decimal

class MyData(BaseModel):
    amount: Optional[Decimal] = Field(ge=0.01, decimal_places=2)

@app.post("send_usd")
async def send_usd(data: MyData):
    pass
```